# Ao selecionar uma opção, ficar marcado a cor da opção selecionada

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte select que está vindo do banco de dados conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
...
while($listar = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){

   $mostrar .= " <select name='Situacao[]' class='md-form-control'>
                  <option value=''>Selecione</option>
                  <option value='Pago' style='background-color: #006400; color: #FFF'>Pago</option>
                  <option value='Não Pago' style='background-color: #F00; color: #FFF'>Não Pago</option>
                  <option value='Aguardando' style='background-color: #FF8C00; color: #FFF'>Aguardando</option>
               </select>";    
}
...
?>
```

E as opções são:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível que ao selecionar uma das opções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O select ficasse com a cor conforme a opção selecionada?

Comment: Olá Isac, sim... mas quando faço isso, o select não fica da cor da opção. Por ex.: se eu selecionar Pago, gostaria que o select ficasse verde, porém ele continua branco.

Comment: Perdão Isac. Alterei meu post. Realmente acabei não sendo claro na minha dúvida.

Comment: Como vi o php, pensei que estava relacionado com o valor, só depois é que me apercebi que o objetivo era o estilo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode obter o estilo da opção selecionada com [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) para o atributo `style` e aplica-lo ao próprio `select`. Para obter o selecionado pode utilizar `find(":selected")`.

Exemplo:

```js
$("select.md-form-control").on("change", function(){
  $(this).attr("style", $(this).find(":selected").attr("style"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='Situacao[]' class='md-form-control'>
    <option value='' style=''>Selecione</option>
    <option value='Pago' style='background-color: #006400; color: #FFF'>Pago</option>
    <option value='Não Pago' style='background-color: #F00; color: #FFF'>Não Pago</option>
    <option value='Aguardando' style='background-color: #FF8C00; color: #FFF'>Aguardando</option>
 </select>
```

Note que tive que incluir um `style=''` na opção `Selecione` para poder voltar ao estilo inicial.

---

Também pode fazer o mesmo com classes que fica mais flexível e escalável. Nesse caso não só a aplicação é ligeiramente diferente, como o próprio html do `<select>` também fica diferente.

Antes de aplicar uma nova classe remove as que já tem com [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) passando só as que queremos remover. Depois obtêm a nova a aplicar do elemento selecionado com `attr('class')`.

Exemplo:

```js
$("select.md-form-control").on("change", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("pago naopago aguardando"); //remover qualquer uma destas classes
  $(this).addClass($(this).find(":selected").attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.pago {
  background-color: #006400; 
  color: #FFF;
}

.naopago {
  background-color: #F00; 
  color: #FFF;
}

.aguardando {
  background-color: #FF8C00; 
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='Situacao[]' class='md-form-control'>
    <option value='' >Selecione</option>
    <option value='Pago' class='pago'>Pago</option>
    <option value='Não Pago' class='naopago'>Não Pago</option>
    <option value='Aguardando' class='aguardando'>Aguardando</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Perfeito Isac. Funcionou! Usei a primeira opção. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @Isac é muito boa, mas gostaria de deixar outra sugestão para referência, onde não é necessário colocar `style=''` na primeira `option` como ele sugeriu.

Com `cssText` você pode reescrever o `style`, e caso não o encontre na `option` (no caso, a primeira), ele ficará vazio voltando o `select` ao estado inicial.

**Veja:**

```js
$("select.md-form-control").on("change", function(){
   this
   .style
   .cssText = $(":selected", this).attr("style");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='Situacao[]' class='md-form-control'>
   <option value=''>Selecione</option>
   <option value='Pago' style='background-color: #006400; color: #FFF'>Pago</option>
   <option value='Não Pago' style='background-color: #F00; color: #FFF'>Não Pago</option>
   <option value='Aguardando' style='background-color: #FF8C00; color: #FFF'>Aguardando</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Olá dvd. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: É de facto uma alternativa interessante

Comment: Obg @Isac......